# Transactional replication in sql server 2017 but job not running

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2017, transactional-replication

I have created transactional replication and here is my script

**Distribution script:**

```
use master
exec sp_adddistributor @distributor = N'servername', @password = N''
GO

exec sp_adddistributiondb @database = N'distribution', 
@data_folder = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data', 
@log_folder = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data', 
@log_file_size = 2, @min_distretention = 0, @max_distretention = 72, @history_retention = 48,
 @deletebatchsize_xact = 5000, @deletebatchsize_cmd = 2000, @security_mode = 1
GO

use [distribution] 
if (not exists (select * from sysobjects where name = 'UIProperties' and type = 'U ')) 
    create table UIProperties(id int) 
if (exists (select * from ::fn_listextendedproperty('SnapshotFolder', 'user', 'dbo', 'table', 'UIProperties', null, null))) 
    EXEC sp_updateextendedproperty N'SnapshotFolder', N'E:\snapshot\ReplData', 'user', dbo, 'table', 'UIProperties' 
else 
    EXEC sp_addextendedproperty N'SnapshotFolder', N'E:\snapshot\ReplData', 'user', dbo, 'table', 'UIProperties'
GO

exec sp_adddistpublisher @publisher = N'servername', 
@distribution_db = N'distribution', 
@security_mode = 1
```

Publication script

```
use [databasename]
exec sp_replicationdboption @dbname = N'databasename', @optname = N'publish', @value = N'true'
GO
use [databasename]
exec [databasename].sys.sp_addlogreader_agent @job_login = N'pcusername',
 @job_password = null, -- pc does not have any password
 @publisher_security_mode = 1, 
 @job_name = null
GO
-- Adding the transactional publication
use [databasename]
exec sp_addpublication @publication = N'Basketball17Pub',
 @description = N'Transactional publication of database ''databasename'' from Publisher ''servername''.', 
 @sync_method = N'concurrent', @retention = 0, @allow_push = N'true', @allow_pull = N'true', 
 @allow_anonymous = N'true', @enabled_for_internet = N'false', 
 @snapshot_in_defaultfolder = N'true', @compress_snapshot = N'false', 
 @ftp_port = 21, @ftp_login = N'anonymous', @allow_subscription_copy = N'false', 
 @add_to_active_directory = N'false', @repl_freq = N'continuous', @status = N'active', 
 @independent_agent = N'true', @immediate_sync = N'true', @allow_sync_tran = N'false', 
 @autogen_sync_procs = N'false', @allow_queued_tran = N'false', @allow_dts = N'false',
 @replicate_ddl = 1, @allow_initialize_from_backup = N'false', @enabled_for_p2p = N'false', 
 @enabled_for_het_sub = N'false'
GO
```

I used one machine for distributor and publication and no network path used for snapshot
but job is not running what i'm missing any suggestion

Comment: Which Job is not running and what is the error that you are getting?  Is it logreader that is erroring out or distribution job?  Also have you stopped at sp_addpublication.  Need to add articles  and then a subscription to that publicatoin.

Comment: in SQL Agent monitoring job not running

Comment: Replication monitoring refresher for distribution. @jesijesi

Comment: To use Replication you must be able to Troubleshoot Replication.  Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/troubleshoot-tran-repl-errors?view=sql-server-ver15